# How to add different controls according to a database field for a survey app?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm creating a survey system. The creator must be able to create a question a decide what kind of control will give the answer (RadioButtonList, TextBox, etc...)

I have a data table (SQL) which stores the question, and the type of desired answer (dbo.Questions):

```
ID (int - PK)
IdForm (int - FK to dbo.Forms)
Question (varchar)
TypeOfAnswer (int)
```

And there's another data table that stores the user answer (dbo.Answers)

```
ID (int - PK)
QuestionId (int - FK to dbo.Questions.ID)
Answer (varchar)
UserId (int - FK to dbo.Users.ID)
Date (datetime)
```

So, one example of questions will be:

```
ID     Question                               TypeOfAnswer
-----------------------------------------------------
1      What color do you like the most?       1
2      Are you happy with your bike?          2
3      What's your favorite ice cream flavor? 3
```

So the question ID.1 should have a RadioButtonList that will display Blue, Yellow, Green as a label and store 1, 2 or 3 as the value, according to the user's selection.

Question ID.2 sholud be RadioButtonList with only two answers, Yes, No for label and 1,2 for stored values.

Question ID3. should be a TextBox.

I'm having a really big struggle when printing the control to the view (on ASP.Net forms).

So far, I've created a dataset, and according to each row, it should print the question's label, and the user control that will store the answer, this is my code so far:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim ptipo As Integer = 2



    Dim tcontrol1 As Control
    tcontrol1 = LoadControl("/WebUSerControl.ascx")



    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(enchufalo1)
    connection.Open()
    Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [BORRAR_CL_Preguntas] WHERE ([IdFormato] = @IdFormato)", connection)
    Dim sqlDa As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd)

    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IdFormato", Request.QueryString("iform"))

    sqlDa.Fill(dt)


    Dim ctipo As Integer
    For Each Row As DataRow In dt.Rows

        ctipo = Row("TypeOfAnswer")

        If ctipo = 1 Then
            Dim rbl As RadioButtonList = New RadioButtonList()
            rbl.ID = "rbl_prg1"
            rbl.Items.Add("1")
            rbl.Items.Add("2")
            rbl.Items.Add("3")

            ph_print.Controls.Add(rbl)

            lit_prg.Text += Row("Question")
            lit_prg.Controls.Add(tcontrol1)

        End If
    Next



End Sub
```

Right now the ph_print placeholder is printing the radiobutton, but skipping the first question!! And I have not been able to add the question label nor HTML styling

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to provide some actual details of what you expect. You have given a rough description of what you want but the code references tables that we don't have and it is not all clear what you have for output. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) are a couple of great things to look at to make this a reasonable question. As it sits right now this is not a question that can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution for this issue...

Here's the front code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_preguntas" runat="server" DataSourceID="DS01">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="Col100">
                                <div class="Col60">
                                    <%#Eval("Pregunta") %>
                                </div>
                                <div class="Col5"></div>
                                <div class="Col35">
                                    <div runat="server" visible='<%# (Eval("Tipo").ToString() = "1") %>'>
                                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="resp_tipo1_rbl" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="6" ValidationGroup="valrspX">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="6">NS/NR</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                    </div>
                                    <div runat="server" visible='<%# (Eval("Tipo").ToString() = "2") %>'>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="tb_tipo2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                    <div runat="server" visible='<%# (Eval("Tipo").ToString() = "3") %>'>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_perros" runat="server">
                                            <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="A">Azul enfermo</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="B">Blanco nigga</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="C">Café popó</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="D">Dorado blin blin</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <br /><br />

                            <asp:Label ID="pregid" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

And the back code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btn_enviar.Click


    Try

        Dim spregid As Integer
        Dim spregrs As String

        For Each elemento As RepeaterItem In rpt_preguntas.Items

            Dim prg_id As Label = DirectCast(elemento.FindControl("pregid"), Label)

            Dim stipo As Integer
            Dim SqlCon0 As SqlConnection
            Dim SqlCom0 As SqlCommand
            Dim SqlDR0 As SqlDataReader
            SqlCon0 = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("EnchufeUNICOC").ToString())
            SqlCom0 = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[BORRAR_CL_Preguntas] WHERE([ID] = '" & prg_id.Text & "')", SqlCon0)
            SqlCom0.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            If SqlCon0.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                SqlCon0.Open()
                'Dim p0 As New SqlParameter("@cc", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                'p0.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                'p0.Value = num_cc
                'SqlCom0.Parameters.Add(p0)
            End If
            SqlDR0 = SqlCom0.ExecuteReader()
            While SqlDR0.Read()

                stipo = SqlDR0("tipo")

            End While
            SqlDR0.Close()
            SqlCon0.Close()

            Dim respuesta As String

            If stipo = 1 Then

                Dim control_t1 As RadioButtonList = DirectCast(elemento.FindControl("resp_tipo1_rbl"), RadioButtonList)



                respuesta = control_t1.SelectedValue

            End If

            If stipo = 2 Then

                Dim control_t2 As TextBox = DirectCast(elemento.FindControl("tb_tipo2"), TextBox)

                respuesta = control_t2.Text

            End If

            If stipo = 3 Then

                Dim control_t3 As DropDownList = DirectCast(elemento.FindControl("ddl_perros"), DropDownList)

                respuesta = control_t3.SelectedValue

            End If

            resultados.Text += "Pregunta ID: " & prg_id.Text & "<br/>Respuesta: " & respuesta & "<br/><br/>"

        Next


    Catch ex As Exception
        resultados.Text = "La cagamos mano:<br/><br/>" & ex.ToString
    End Try

End Sub
```

So it was solved by adding a conditional to the Repeater control in it's ItemTemplate!